# Visual Basic .NET 2010 Build/Debug Output Window Disappeared On Me

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Gurus...

When building my app in VB 2010, I have always been accustomed to the debug output window that, if any errors were present, the errors and warnings would be in color (yellow, red, etc) and I could actually click on the error in the output window and it would take me to that part of my code that had the problem.

Then, for some unknown reason, that output window just vanished and doesn't show up anymore.

I have searched the forums, but all I see is people telling other people to just go to Tools/Options/Debugging/General and enable to output window.  The problem is that this is NOT the same output Window that vanished on me.  This only enables a basic no-frills text window with no intuitive links or color coding like the original.  Going into Projects and Solutions/Build and Run and setting output options in there only change the amount and complexity of plain text in the same output window, so again, the problem remains.

Anybody in here know how to restore the original build debug window that VS 2010 (VB) uses as default upon installation?  I have a feeling the solution is embarrassingly simple, but I still haven't come across it yet.  I still don't even know how it disappeared on me in the first place, and I really miss it.

Comment: Use View > Error List

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!